# How to include test classes with init in a Pytest test suite?

Tags: python, pytest

I'm trying to create a test suite with pytest and Selenium using Page Object Models for pattern designing. For using my page classes on my tests, I just imported them inside my TestClass `__init__` method, since they need to instanced with a driver.

I know that, by default, pytest ignores classes with an `__init__` method. I also know, by reading [here](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/goodpractices.html#conventions-for-python-test-discovery) that it's possible to configure where pytest collects tests. Is it also possible to make it consider class tests with `__init__`, instead of returning an "Empty Suite" error?

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def driver_init(request):
    from selenium import webdriver
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    session = request.node
    page = PageFunctions(driver)
    login_page = LoginPage(driver)
    registration_page = RegistrationPage(driver)

    for item in session.items:
        cls = item.getparent(pytest.Class)
        setattr(cls.obj, "driver", driver)
        setattr(cls.obj, "page", page)
        setattr(cls.obj, "login", login_page)
        setattr(cls.obj, "registration", registration_page)
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of your source?

Comment: I actually managed a workaround by bypassing needing an `__init__` method and using my driver_init pytest fixture to start what I needed. For reference, this is the code I ended up using to start the classes I needed and use them as class atributes in my test classes

Answer (score 0):

Pytest and Unittest have some different conventions.  Mixing the two in the same test function is usually worth avoiding.

If you're working exclusively with Pytest, you would pass in your fixtures as arguments to your test function, e.g.:

```
import pytest
from selenium import webdriver


@pytest.fixture
def driver():
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    return driver


def test_func(driver):
    # `driver` is found by pytest in the fixture above and
    # automatically passed in
    request = ... # Instantiate your request (not in your included code)

    session = request.node
    page = PageFunctions(driver)
    login_page = LoginPage(driver)
    registration_page = RegistrationPage(driver)

    # Make some assertions about your data, e.g.:
    assert page is not None
```

You haven't included all of the object definitions/imports so it's hard to see what you're trying to accomplish with the test, but hopefully that gives you an idea of the pytest conventions.